# Options for single page view / Book view in com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml

Tags: epub, ibooks

Is there any option to change the apperance to pageview/Book view in  com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml file for epub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. At the moment you can only do page view for fixed layout books and book view is the only option for reflowable...

More on fixed layout ePubs here: http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Fixed_layout_ePub.